# Get array of property in stdClass array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have and array of StdClass objects ass follows:

```
0 => {#491
+"venue_id": 5355
+"distance": 0.68115836642929
}
1 => {#490
+"venue_id": 5354
+"distance": 1.2191811657926
}
2 => {#494
+"venue_id": 5357
+"distance": 1.4241327433078
}
```

These results are being retrieved from a database query (using laravel)
How can get `venues_id`s in an array? The outcome would look like something like:

```
0=> 5355, 1=> 5354, 2=> 5357
```

I can think of iterating the stdClass but is there any built in function to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$arr = array_map(function($x) { return $x->venue_id; }, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7+, [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) supports passing in an array of objects:

```
$venue_ids = array_column($array, 'venue_id')
```